# All my contracts is in pending state for last 72 hours?

Tags: contract-debugging, pending-transactions

Ok guys, where is the problem? Gas? Gas price? Something else?

TXhashes:

```
0x0f9c73d12db222cf820e8831007be326fc666dac88a2daefe3e19e44a820de1c
```

**500k * 3gw - 4 days gone**

```
0x10fbccbdabbee095007942afb28e463d00fa3e0fddae0bd83ba1cf4415522e24
```

**this transaction should change gas params in previous one contract to    40GW *500k. 24 hours gone, still no luck.**

```
0xe5c582b5defb8ba5598e37acb2fe49061f44d20d526af822fc3eaee3c6a378e9
```

**this one is the same copy of the first one with increased gas variables (5.9kk*42GW). 22 hours no luck**

```
0xc555b0a12fac7f29671e09992676f033b7063d5d70b8025838d5454b368998e5
```

**this one is the copy of the first one but with 2.5kk * 42GW , more than 18   hours, luck status still the same.**

Thank you for your attention and maybe answers, im a bit nervous around all this situation and i want to understand if this problem in 'cause of blockchain overload.

Comment: more than 18 hours? The etherscan[https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe5c582b5defb8ba5598e37acb2fe49061f44d20d526af822fc3eaee3c6a378e9] shows only 1 hour. You can wait for some time and see if transactions get mined. I think 42Gwei is a handsome amount of gas. Your transaction should get included in a block.

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh thank you for your attention. But now it shows  05 min 28 secs  , but i've added it more than 18 hours ago, that is one these moments i am warring about. why this param shows not actual creation datetime ?

Comment: yeah man. It's starting again and again. I have not anything as such before. Also, everything seems fine. Your contract should get mined.